# Parameterizing the return type of a method using an enum -- possible?

Tags: java, generics

In java, I know it's possible to e.g.:

```java
static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
    for (T o : a) {
        c.add(o); // Correct
    }
}
```

In my scenario, I have an enumeration of different settings I can retrieve a value for, where each setting has a different value type.  I'd like to specify these value types in the enumeration, and get compile-time checking similar to the above.

Here is a version with runtime checking -- is compile-time checking possible?

```java
public class Foo {
  public static enum ClientSetting {
    SOME_STRING_SETTING(String.class),
    SOME_INTEGER_SETTING(Integer.class);

    private Class valueClass;

    ClientSetting(Class valueClass) {
      this.valueClass = valueClass;
    }
  }

  public static <T> T get(ClientSetting bar) {
    if (bar.valueClass.equals(String.class))
      return (T) "My string value.";
    else if (bar.valueClass.equals(Integer.class))
      return (T) new Integer(2);
    else
      return null; // unreachable if every possibility is  checked
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringValue = get(ClientSetting.SOME_STRING_SETTING);
    Integer integerValue = get(ClientSetting.SOME_INTEGER_SETTING);
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have to say, an type similar to `public interface ClientSettings { String someStringSetting(); int someIntegerSetting(); ... }` would be vastly preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dacc, would something like this work for you?

```
public static class ClientSetting<T> {
   private T setting;

   ClientSetting(T setting) {
      this.setting = setting;
   }

   public T get() {
      return setting;
   }
}

// Old school, I know.
public static final ClientSetting<String> SOME_STRING_SETTING = 
   new ClientSetting<String>("My string value.");
public static final ClientSetting<Integer> SOME_INTEGER_SETTING = 
   new ClientSetting<Integer>(2);

public static <T> T get(ClientSetting<T> clientSetting) {
   // delegation, this method is not really needed
   // you can go for SOME_STRING_SETTING.get()
   return clientSetting.get();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   String stringValue = get(SOME_STRING_SETTING);
   Integer integerValue = get(SOME_INTEGER_SETTING);
   // Won't compile
   // String wrong = get(SOME_INTEGER_SETTING);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Anthony.  I think something like this approach is the way to go.  i.e. Using something like a case class instead of an actual Java language enum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would help, but what if you put a generic on ClientSetting?  You could pass around `ClientSetting<String>` or `ClientSetting<Integer>`.  Assuming you were coding to a specific one of these, some compile-time checking would occur.

Comment: Unfortunately you will receive a nasty "Syntax error, enum declaration cannot have type parameters".

Comment: @Anthony Accioly You could have separate enums for types: `public enum StringSetting implements ClientStting<String>` (where `ClientSetting` is an interface).

Comment: @Tom you are right. This would also be a nice way to group settings by type. The client would only declare variables of the interface type and everything would work as expected. But I must say that every time I stumble upon Java generics limitations like this I miss Scala type system, case classes, mixins, etc :D. Do you know why java enums can't have type parameters? Would it be impossible for some kind of technical reason? Could it be done with Type Erasure?

Comment: @Anthony Accioly I don't know why you can't have a generic enum. I don't see any erasure issues (you get arrays of enums [should have been Lists], but `MyEnum<?>` works fine). At the moment all enum constants of the same enum have the same type, so it may have complicated the spec. Likewise, abstract enums are possible, just complicate the spec more than is considered worthwhile.